# How to split Row into multiple column using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are three column,wherever D_ID=13,value_amount holds value for mode of payment and wherever D_ID=10,value_amount holds value for amount.

```
ID D_ID Value_amount
1   13   2
1   13   2
1   10   1500
1   10   1500
2   13   1
2   13   1
2   10   2000
2   10   2000
```

Now I have to add two more columns amount and mode_of_payment and result should come like below

```
ID  amount mode_of_payment
1   1500  2
1   1500  2
2   2000  1
2   2000  1
```

Comment: Seems like you have a data issue here. How do you know which row is related to which, when they have no linking ID? For example, why is the 1st row not linked to both the 3rd and 4th rows? Out of the 2, is it related to the 3rd or 4th?  How do you know? Why isn't it's linked to the 2nd? What would you expect to have to the 4th row (in your displayed data) have a value of `1000` for `Value_Amount` and the 1st a value of `2`? You *really* need to fix this design.

Comment: From ID field I know that Row no 1-4 are related to each other,its just that I have to divide column  value_amount into two columns amount and mode_of_payment.I hope its helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Simply put, your data is severely flawed. For the example data you've given, you're "ok", because the rows have the same values to the same ID, but what about when they don't? Let's assume, for example, we have data that looks like this:

```
ID D_ID  Value_amount
1   13   1           --1
1   13   2           --2
1   10   1500        --3
1   10   1000        --4
2   13   1           --5
2   13   2           --6
2   10   2000        --7
2   10   3000        --8
```

I've added a "row number" next to data, for demonstration purposes only.

Here, what row is row "1" related to? Row "3" or row "4"? How do you know? There's no always ascending value in your data, so row "3" could just as easily be row "4". In fact, if we were to order the data using `ID ASC, D_ID DESC, Value_amount ASC` then rows 3 and 4 would "swap" in order. This could mean that when you attempt a solution, the order in wrong.

Tables aren't stored in any particular order, that are unordered. What determines the order the data is presented in is the `ORDER BY` clause, and if you don't have a value to define that "order", then that "order" is lost as soon as you `INSERT` it.

If, however, we add a always ascending value into your data, you *can* achieve this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (UID int IDENTITY,
                            ID int,
                            DID int,
                            Value_amount int);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID, DID, Value_amount)
VALUES (1,13,1   ),
       (1,13,2   ),
       (1,10,1500),
       (1,10,1000),
       (2,13,1   ),
       (2,13,2   ),
       (2,10,2000),
       (2,10,3000);
GO

WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT ID,
           DID,
           Value_amount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DID ORDER BY UID ASC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE DID WHEN 13 THEN Value_Amount END) AS Amount,
       MAX(CASE DID WHEN 10 THEN Value_Amount END) AS PaymentMode
FROM RNs
GROUP BY RN,
         ID;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Of course, you need to fix your design to implement this, but you **need** to do that anyway.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, thanks for your answer. For me, values are going to be same.